# Altium & Patterned Colors

Tags: altium

Is is possible to add color fill patterns to standard design layer colors in Altium Designer?   I can only find and use solid and transparent colors for all design layers, but cannot figure out if or how to give colors a fillstyle.

This example (taken from EAGLE ) shows a top metal pad (red) with solder mask over it ( grey with hatched pattern )      Is it possible to make design layers appear similarly hatched in Altium?

[image]

Comment: There is a whole Colour and Layers window, perhaps there is some hidden awesome settings in there?

Comment: I've thoroughly explored the Layers window;  all colors seem to be solid with no options ( at least that I can find ) for patterned colors.  Wondering if I can somehow hack the colors and/or View Configuration to allow for hatched patterns ...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check out this stuff http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/PCB+Object+and+Layer+Transparency

and see here on the layers/view config window:
[image: screenshot]

There is also [this youtube video](http://youtu.be/m9HmU2QvP_4) which shows how to set layer transparencies really easily, but you need Altium Designer 13 or above.

This is as close as I can find to help you, otherwise have a look at Mechanical Layer 1 for 3D objects and maybe find how they do the purple diagonal cross hatching to show 3D bodies in 2D mode.. maybe there is something you can take from those view options and apply them to your needs?